# Is it possible to prevent/stop xcodebuild from rebuilding everything

Tags: xcode, build

I am trying to compile my project twice in a row, just with one preprocessor defined for the second build. (this #define is only used in one source file)

However when i call xcodebuild for the second time it rebuild everything! Using LLVM Compiler 3.0. XCode 4.2

Comment: Where is the #define?  If it is in a .h file, every source file that includes it will have to be re-built when it is changed.  Since it is only used in one source file, you could either place it in it's own .h file and import it to the one source file or include it directly in the source file that needs it.  This way other files won't have to be rebuilt just because they include your source file's .h!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean pre-processor flag? Whats the difference between the two builds? Just asking because sometimes there are other ways to achieve the same result.

You need to give us some more details and examples of you command lines etc.

Comment: Yes i mean pre-processor flag. The second build is for beta, and has a splash screen letting the user know that that is the case.

The command im using on the command line is xcodebuild .xcodeproj -target -configuration -arch "GCC_PREPROCESSORDEFINITIONS = $PREPROCESSOR"

where $PREPROCESSOR is my pre-processor defines.

Ive also noticed that if i call the same line twice (with the same $PREPROCESSOR args) the build still rebuilds

Answer (score 0):

Ijust did a quick google and checked the Xcode doco, GCC_PREPROCESSORDEFINITIONS should be GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS. Xcodebuild is simply ignoring your setting because it doesn't recognise it.

Comment: that was a typo i have GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS